# Do microprocessor have any special hardware to do division and multiplicaiton?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, microprocessor

My old school understanding is that multiplication is nothing but successive addition and division is nothing but successive subtraction. So, my question is there any changes being done like do we have a hardware that does the division and multiplication in one machine cycle or go.

For e.g, if I have 2 registers of 64 bits, and if I multiply them, I can get an overflow i.e. I need two 64 registers to store the result. So, when I do multiply do the modern RISC processor does successive addition behind the scene or does it do just multiplication. Is there a hardware that can do just multiplication rather than using full adder?

Answer (score 2):

Some faster and larger processors have hardware multiplier and some slower and smaller don't. Division can be also made faster with hardware. If there is no hardware to help, the software needs to perform multiplication and division with a software algorithm. While successive addition and subtraction can do it, there are faster ways to do it, for example multiply can be performed with shifting and adding.

Answer (score 2):

Some modern RISC processors have dedicated integer multiplication (or multiply-add or MAC) circuit blocks, some very small or low power ones don’t (some of the earliest RISC ISAs didn’t even have a MUL instruction).

The multiply logic blocks are often just a bunch of layers of (3 input, 2 output) [carry-save adders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder) (mostly XOR gates), sometimes stacked, sometimes pipelined, with attached carry propagation logic (look-ahead or carry-select are two common types).  Similar to a fast adder, just a lot deeper, and with a single carry block, instead of one for each adder layer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a ALU, or **A**rithmetic **L**ogic **U**nit. It does the integer, floating point and binary/boolean operations all in hardware, with things like square-roots needing extra CPU cycles. In some cases floating point is handled by a local FP engine. Now days extra help from vector processors on another card or as part of a video card (CUDA cores) or GPU can process huge arrays of numbers. Todays 64 bit operating systems handle the background details. Extended floating point handles 128 bit math. Hardware based multipliers are common.

To multiply or divide by powers of 2 a shift register is used, faster than a complex ALU. You are thinking of the way things were decades ago.

Normally the simpler and much lower cost MPU's can do integers/hardware multiply and possibly floating point to 64 bits. These are mostly for machine control with built-in graphics/USB/Ethernet and seldom exceed 200 MHZ to save power. They can do machine control with ease, but are no competition for a Intel i7 or AMD Ryzen CPU running at 3 GHZ to 5 GHZ.

Comment: Generally an ALU does not do hardware floating point.  There may be exceptions, but usually if hardware floating point is present it  is a separate functional unit in the processor using its own registers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have added a sentence to exclude the ALU from doing FP math. I also VTC this post as all answers, including mine, are but opinions.

Answer (score 0):

There are ALU multiplication units : [Source of image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier)

[image]

[image]

The very basic MCU, CPU has the ALU with multiplication/division capabilities. However you can build an ALU without it, but it can be still called an ALU. The very first computers didn't had an ALU with such capabilities, therefore the mul/div was made with a program that was shifting and adding. Such ALU is a popular [7418](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/74181).